# How to write query with dynamic columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following tables

```
 PeopleInformation
```

with  the following columns:

```
 PeopleID,
 FirstName,
 LastName,
 DOB,
 Email,
 ContactNo etc
```

and another table

```
ColumnInformation
```

with  the following columns:

```
ColumnID
ColumnName
UserID
```

so userwise column is added in ColumnInformation table.
so let say user with userid =1  then I need to display columns only assigned to him

So, I want to write query which generate PeopleInformation records from columnInformaiton by UserID

Comment: Could you post some sample data and expected results?

Comment: I believe this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041553/dynamically-select-the-columns-to-be-used-in-a-select-statement) is what you're after. `UserId` -> `ColumnName`(s) and select only these columns from `PeopleInformation`. You should consider restructuring though.

Comment: this sounds like an odd design. If you want to restrict the number of columns which are displayed, based on whether they apply to that user, the more conventional way to do it is to return all the columns, but then in your display you can, if you wish, hide the ones which return null for that user.

Comment: How do you preserve records for a particular user in ColumnInformation table. either row wise or comma separated list

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are maintaining column details as row wise for each and every user. Please refer this,

```
DECLARE @UserId INT = 2
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = ''
    ,@columnlist NVARCHAR(max) = ''
DECLARE @ColumnInformation TABLE (
    ColumnID INT identity(1, 1)
    ,ColumnName VARCHAR(50)
    ,UserID INT
    )

insert into @ColumnInformation
values 
('PeopleID',1)
,('FirstName',1)
,('LastName',1)
,('DOB',1)
,('Email',1)
,('ContactNo',1)
,('PeopleID',2)
,('FirstName',2)
,('LastName',2)

SELECT @columnlist = @columnlist + ',' + ColumnName
FROM @ColumnInformation
WHERE UserID = @UserId

SELECT @columnlist = stuff(@columnlist, 1, 1, '')

SET @sql = 'select ' + @columnlist + ' from PeopleInformation'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```